# Phonebook App: if a number is added to an already existing user, the new number will replace the old number

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Currently have a phonebook App created with React, that will take a name and a number from a form and display it on screen and also store the data on a server.

I am looking to improve the functionality so that if a number is added to an already existing user, the app will ask if you would like to replace the old number with the new number.

Here is my function for adding an entry to the phone book

```
const addName = (event) => {
event.preventDefault()
const nameObject = {
  name: newName,
  number: newNumber,
}

if (persons.some(person =>person.name ===
  `${newName}`) )
  
 {
  alert(`${newName}` + " is already added to phonebook, replace the old number with a new one?")
  
  

 }
 else
 {
  personsService
   .create(nameObject)
   .then(returnedName => {
    setPersons(persons.concat(returnedName))
    setNewName('')
    setNewNumber('')
    console.log(persons.id)
```

})
}

I created a new function to update the entry

```
const changeNumberOf = id => {
  const url = `http://localhost:3001/persons/${id}`
  const person = persons.find(n => n.id === id)
  const changedPerson = { ...person} // here I need to update to the new number

  axios.put(url, changedPerson).then(response => {
    setPersons(persons.map(person => person.id !== id ? person : response.data))
  })
}
```

My question is how will I get the Id of the entry I need to update from my addName function so I can then update it with the new phone number?

Picture added below of what app will look like when functioning correctly.

Any help appreciated

[image: example of what app will look like]

Full code attached below

```
const App = () => {
  const [persons, setPersons] = useState([
   ])
  const [ newName, setNewName ] = useState('')
  const [ newNumber, setNewNumber] = useState('')
  const [ searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('')


  useEffect(() => {
    personsService
    .getAll()
    .then(currentNames => {
      setPersons(currentNames)
    })
}, [])

const addName = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    const nameObject = {
      name: newName,
      number: newNumber,
    }
    
    if (persons.some(person =>person.name ===
      `${newName}`) )
      
     {
      alert(`${newName}` + " is already added to phonebook, replace the old number with a new one?")
      
 }
     else
     {
      personsService
       .create(nameObject)
       .then(returnedName => {
        setPersons(persons.concat(returnedName))
        setNewName('')
        setNewNumber('')
        console.log(persons.id)
  })
     }
  } 
  const handleNewName = (event) => {
   // console.log(event.target.value)
    setNewName(event.target.value)
  }

  const handleNewNumber = (event) => {
    setNewNumber(event.target.value)
  }

 const deletePersons = id => {
    const requestOptions = {
      method: 'DELETE'
    };
    fetch("http://localhost:3001/persons/" + id , requestOptions)
      personsService 
      .getAll()
      .then(initialNames => {
        setPersons(initialNames)
      }
      )}
      
     const changeNumberOf = id => {
      const url = `http://localhost:3001/persons/${id}`
      const person = persons.find(n => n.id === id)
      const changedPerson = { ...person, important: !person.important }
    
      axios.put(url, changedPerson).then(response => {
        setPersons(persons.map(person => person.id !== id ? person : response.data))
      })
    }

return (
    
    <div classname="App">
      <h2>Phonebook</h2>
      <input 
      type="text" 
      placeholder="Search..."
      onChange={event => {setSearchTerm(event.target.value)}} />
        

      <h2>Add a new</h2>
      <form onSubmit={addName}>
        <div>
          name: <input 
          value={newName}
          onChange={handleNewName}
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          number: <input
          value={newNumber}
          onChange={handleNewNumber}
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <button type="submit">add</button>
        </div>
      </form>

<h2>Numbers</h2>
      {persons.filter((val) => {
          if (searchTerm == "") {
        return val
          } 
          else if (val.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())) {
            return val
          }
         }) .map(person => 
          <div classname="user">
          <li key={person.name}>{person.name}{person.number}
          </li>
        </div>
      
        )
        }
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the `persons.some()` with a for loop:

```
let personMatch = null;

for(const person of persons){
    if(person.name === newName){
        personMatch = person;
        // stop the loop, we have found someone
        break;
    }
}

if(personMatch !== null){
  // changeNumberOf(personMatch.id) I guess
} else {
  // no matching person found
}
```

Comment: Thank you will try that